# Problem with add variable to new FormData object in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

If  data: new FormData($(this)[0])  all ok and I have all info about file, but

why if data: new FormData($(this)[0]).append("var","value"),  handler.php return {"result":[]}

What is the problem?

```
<form method="post" action="upload/image" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"><div class="simple-button" action="handler.php" id="browse-button"><label><input type="file" name="photo" id="fileUpload">
              <span>File...</span></label></div>

    </form>


    $("form").submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({

             type: 'POST',
              url: 'handler.php',
             data: new FormData($(this)[0]),

            processData: false, 
            contentType: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                 cache: false,

               success:    function(data) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(jsonData.result);


    });


    });

handler.php

$arr = array('result' => $_FILES);

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Change to `new FormData(event.currentTarget)`

Comment: The result remained the same.

Comment: so you want to send both files and field values inside formdata ?

Comment: Yes, I want to send a image file and one variabe with name 'var'

Comment: `event.preventDefault();
const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
for (const [key, val] of formData.entries()) {
 console.log(key, val);
}` Try inspecting the value inside the formData object by submitting your form with this code

Comment: I tried so: beforeSend: {   const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    for (const [key, val] of formData.entries()) { console.log(key, val); }
    
  }, but it not work.

Comment: Just put the code `event.preventDefault(); const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget); for (const [key, val] of formData.entries()) { console.log(key, val); }` in the submit handler ` $("form").submit(function (event) {`

Comment: It's return: photo 
File {name: "filename.jpg", lastModified: 1587536177883, lastModifiedDate: Wed Apr 22 2020 09:16:17 GMT+0300, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 18129, …}
lastModified: 1587536177883
lastModifiedDate: Wed Apr 22 2020 09:16:17 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время) {}
name: "filename.jpg"
size: 18129
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File